# Tkinter - Code is executed without tkinter reacting

Tags: python, tkinter

while trying to create a countdown timer, I have ran into a problem. I have based myself on Bryan Oakleys code ([Making a countdown timer with Python and Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596988/making-a-countdown-timer-with-python-and-tkinter)) I did not post the whole code because that would be quite long.

**What I want my code to do:**

Wait for x amount of seconds, stored in Wait and collected by the entry WaitE.
Next, I want the wait_button to call the Countdown call. This class will create a label in its own tkinter window. After the countdown (= an x seconds delay) the main function will be recalled and change the flow.

**What it does:**

The code is executed without errors. A countdown takes place, and the flows are changed, but without a second delay and without opening a tkinter window.

Any help would be appreciated, I looked on the site but did not find anything that really helped to resolve my problem.

Stijn

```
def Wait_button(self):
     """This is part of a larger tkinter grid and is called after pushing a button"""
     """Wait for a set ammount of time before changing""" 
     self.Flow = self.Collect()
     self.WaitE = int(self.WaitE.get())
     Countdown(self.Flow, self.WaitE)
     return()

class Countdown():   

    def __init__(self, Flow, WaitE):

        self.master = Tk()
        self.label = Label(self.master, text="", width=10)
        self.label.pack()
        self.remaining = WaitE
        self.Flow =  Flow
        self.counting(Flow, self.remaining)

    def counting(self, Flow, remaining = None):

        print(Flow, "after init")
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if int(self.remaining) <= 0:
            self.master.destroy()
            Go = AskInput(root)
            Go.Change_now(Flow)

        else:
            print(self.remaining, "-1")
            self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.label.after(1000, self.counting(self.Flow))
```

Comment: Try replacing the line with `after` with `self.label.after(1000, lambda: self.counting(self.Flow))`.

Comment: Perfect! It works. Can you explain the importance of the lamda in this case?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: you don't need to use `lambda` with `after`: you can pass in arguments: `self.label.after(1000, self.counting, self.Flow)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by TigerhawkT3.

"Try replacing the line with after with self.label.after(1000, lambda: self.counting(self.Flow))"

Comment: You don't need to use lambda, it just adds unnecessary complexity. You can directly pass arguments from within the function call: `self.label.after(1000, self.counting, self.Flow)`

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Your answers on SO have already helped me multiple times.

Comment: In the end the answer is very simple but I did not see it.