# How to add a time countdown to tkinter tittle

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter GUI form which now showing some text from text file.
Now i have a countdown module as below:

```
def countdown(t):
 while t:
    mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
    timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
    print(timeformat, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1
```

How can i show this countdown at tkinter tittle which show the time left for program reload ?

Thanks

Comment: there are probably dozens of questions on this site related to creating counters with tkinter. Please do a little research before asking such a broad, basic questino.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a countdown timer with Python and Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596988/making-a-countdown-timer-with-python-and-tkinter)

Comment: I have already have countdown code, just want to make it work for showing on tittle. There is no answer there

Comment: @ahtacs I have added an answer showing how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short program that updates the title according to your code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
def changeTitle(root, val, t):
    root.title(val)
    root.after(1000, lambda:countdown(t-1, root))
def countdown(t, root):
     if t+1:
         mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
         timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
         changeTitle(root, timeformat, t)
     else:
         return
root=Tk()
countdown(10, root)
mainloop()
```