# Trying to code a 5 second countdown timer in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, countdown

This is the code I have written, I don't understand why but nothing appears on my canvas.

```
def countdown():
    for n in range(5, 0, -1):
        nr = Label(root, text=n, font="helvetica 25 bold", bg="white")
        nr.place(x=590, y=420)
        nr.destroy()
```

Comment: Might it be because you immediately destroy it?

Comment: If this is all the code you wrote, you never import anything, you never create a root window, you never call `mainloop`, and you never call your function.

Comment: To add to the previous answers, because you have this inside a loop, the GUI doesn't have a chance to redraw with the new label. There is also no time delay between each number so from a human perspective the numbers won't be visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a countdown timer with Python and Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596988/making-a-countdown-timer-with-python-and-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Use root.after(timer, function). Best way to do it s calling `root.after(1000, your_func, count-1)` your_func should configure the text of the label to "count".