# thread.interrupt_main() doesn't work when waiting for input

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

I've read about this technique to timeout blocking IO operations, the problem is that it doesn't seem to work. for example:

```
import thread, threading
   
def read_timeout(prompt, timeout=10.0):
    timer = threading.Timer(timeout, thread.interrupt_main)
    s = ''
    timer.start()
    
    try:
        s = raw_input(prompt)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'operation timed out.'
        
    timer.cancel()
    return s
    
s = read_timeout('enter input: ')

if s:
    print 'you entered: %s' % s
```

this won't interrupt the main thread until `raw_input()` returns.
Any help is appreciated.

#### Update:

Using `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)` instead of `thread.interrupt_main()` seems to work (at least on Linux, which doesn't give me the portability I initially wanted). However, I'm still wondering why the code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest doc of the API: https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#thread.interrupt_main

> This does not emit the corresponding signal but schedules a call to the associated handler (if it exists).

And the call is performed after the current blocking call in the main thread.

On the other hand, the `os.kill` solution mentioned in the update immediately emits a signal to the main thread.

Sorry that it's been quite a while since the question was raised, but hopefully it still helps.

Comment: It did help me with a similar issue, thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

On Unix machines, there is a way to do what you are trying to do. Look at this post:
[raw_input and timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout/3911560#3911560)

Just remove the comma at the end of line 5, or the prompt won't be displayed until the program is terminated.

On the same page there's also solution for Windows OS, but I haven't tested it to know if it's working.

Comment: I know about select, but I was looking for something portable :)
also the main reason I posted the question is because I wanted to know what's wrong with my code.