# How to interrupt a sleeping python process

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, signals, interrupt

I tried to write generic timeout-context-manager, and can't get it to work properly:

```py
import signal
import contextlib
from threading import Thread
from _thread import interrupt_main  # 3.10 and up only
import time


class CustomInterrupt(Exception):
    SIG = 63  # I can only test on linux


def handle_custom_interrupt(signum, _):
    raise CustomInterrupt


signal.signal(CustomInterrupt.SIG, handle_custom_interrupt)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def timeout(seconds: float = 3.0):
    class TimedOut:
        def __init__(self, seconds_: float):
            self.seconds: float = seconds_
            self.state: bool | None = None
            self.thread = Thread(target=self._task)

        def _task(self):
            time.sleep(self.seconds)
            if self.state is None:
                interrupt_main(CustomInterrupt.SIG)

        def start(self):
            self.thread.start()

        def __bool__(self):
            if self.state is None:
                raise ValueError("Can't decide yet, value is only meaningful on exit.")
            return self.state

    timed_out = TimedOut(seconds)
    try:
        timed_out.start()
        yield timed_out
        timed_out.state = False
    except CustomInterrupt:
        timed_out.state = True
    finally:
        timed_out.thread.join()
```

Interrupting an endless loop works:

```py
with timeout(1) as t_o:
    while True:
        pass
print(f"escaped! timed out: {bool(t_o)}")  # prints "escaped! timed out: True" after 1 second
```

Interrupting a non-responsive request doesn't:

```py
import requests
with timeout(1) as t_o:
    requests.get("http://www.google.com:81/")
print(f"escaped! timed out: {bool(t_o)}")  # prints "escaped! timed out: True" after 130 seconds
```

Interrupting sleep doesn't:

```py
with timeout(1) as t_o:
    time.sleep(5)
print(f"escaped! timed out: {bool(t_o)}")  # prints "escaped! timed out: True" after 5 seconds
```

While the fact that it can escape from an infinite loop proves that it works in principle, failing on the two actual use cases is unfortunate.

Some additional context and things I wonder about:

- Changing the `time.sleep` instruction in `TimedOut._task` to `subprocess.run(["sleep", str(self.seconds)])` doesn't change anything, so it's not a GIL-and-threads thing
- Switching from a thread to `subprocess.Popen` would be the next step, but would make the state-information-exchange a pain, so I wanted to make this post just in case all of this also works with threads and I'm just doing something wrong
- The fact that `bool(timed_out)` returns `True` even in the cases where the interrupt didn't work means that excepting the `CustomInterrupt` still took place, but only when the code in the `with`-block was done running. Why/what is it blocking? Can I make it non-blocking, and send/handle the signal immediately?
- When I ctrl+c while the code is running, it crashes just fine. I don't know which conclusion to draw from this, but I did this as a sanity-check.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005239/3440745) explains that `thread.interrupt_main` just **schedulers** a handler for being executed in the main thread. Such scheduling doesn't interrupt current blocking call in the main thread. Instead, the answer suggests to use `os.kill`. Have you tried that?

Comment: It works! Thanks for finding that. Want to post that as an answer?