# How to update parameters using subprocess (python)

Tags: python, parameters, subprocess

Here I have two scripts: main.py and sub.py

- sub.py is a wxpython based app which just show a text (received as a
  required parameter, for example: sub.py "Hello world!").
- In main.py, it calls sub.py using subprocess and send a parameter at
  first call.

**And my problem is how to update the corresponding parameter of sub.py in main.py which re-send a new parameter without restart (or recall) sub.py?**
Something like these in main.py:

```
subprocess.Popen('sub.py "Hello, world"')
subprocess.update('sub.py "Hi, world!"')#(just update the parameter without reopen sub.py)<br>
```

Is this possible? So how to design such programs that communicate each other? 
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update the parameters that were used to start a program. However, you can use other forms of interprocess communication to do so. An easy way would be to have "sub.py" read its parameters from standard input. Each time it reads a new line, it will display new text.

Comment: +1, I think you'd need something like `select` so that the UI thread wouldn't freeze when waiting for stdin. It won't easily work for Windows though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499523/using-sys-stdin-in-select-select-on-windows?lq=1

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! "stdin/stdout" via subprocess.PIPE is a good way!!

Comment: You can avoid the UI from freezing by running a separate thread that reads stdin and puts the data into a `Queue` which the main thread can pull information from whenever it pleases.

Comment: If memory serves me well wxPython already uses a separate event thread for GUI events. But using a queue pattern is good advice anyway.