# Simple chat program connecting windows and mac: "operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, chat

I am working on this simple chat program with a student studying Python.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-chat-room-using-python/

I set up the server on my macbook, with

```
python server.py 0.0.0.0 6677
```

where server.py is the script:

```
# Python program to implement server side of chat room.
import socket
import select
import sys
from thread import *
 
"""The first argument AF_INET is the address domain of the
socket. This is used when we have an Internet Domain with
any two hosts The second argument is the type of socket.
SOCK_STREAM means that data or characters are read in
a continuous flow."""
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
 
# checks whether sufficient arguments have been provided
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print ("Correct usage: script, IP address, port number")
    exit()
 
# takes the first argument from command prompt as IP address
IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
 
# takes second argument from command prompt as port number
Port = int(sys.argv[2])
 
"""
binds the server to an entered IP address and at the
specified port number.
The client must be aware of these parameters
"""
server.bind((IP_address, Port))
 
"""
listens for 100 active connections. This number can be
increased as per convenience.
"""
server.listen(100)
 
list_of_clients = []
 
def clientthread(conn, addr):
 
    # sends a message to the client whose user object is conn
    conn.send("Welcome to this chatroom!")
 
    while True:
            try:
                message = conn.recv(2048)
                if message:
 
                    """prints the message and address of the
                    user who just sent the message on the server
                    terminal"""
                    print ("<" + addr[0] + "> " + message)
 
                    # Calls broadcast function to send message to all
                    message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message
                    broadcast(message_to_send, conn)
 
                else:
                    """message may have no content if the connection
                    is broken, in this case we remove the connection"""
                    remove(conn)
 
            except:
                continue
 
"""Using the below function, we broadcast the message to all
clients who's object is not the same as the one sending
the message """
def broadcast(message, connection):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients!=connection:
            try:
                clients.send(message)
            except:
                clients.close()
 
                # if the link is broken, we remove the client
                remove(clients)
 
"""The following function simply removes the object
from the list that was created at the beginning of
the program"""
def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)
 
while True:
 
    """Accepts a connection request and stores two parameters,
    conn which is a socket object for that user, and addr
    which contains the IP address of the client that just
    connected"""
    conn, addr = server.accept()
 
    """Maintains a list of clients for ease of broadcasting
    a message to all available people in the chatroom"""
    list_of_clients.append(conn)
 
    # prints the address of the user that just connected
    print (addr[0] + " connected")
 
    # creates and individual thread for every user
    # that connects
    start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,addr))    
 
conn.close()
server.close()
```

Then, on the same macbook, to add a user,

```
python client.py 0.0.0.0 6677
```

where client.py is the script

```
# Python program to implement client side of chat room.
import socket
import select
import sys
 
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print ("Correct usage: script, IP address, port number")
    exit()
IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
Port = int(sys.argv[2])
server.connect((IP_address, Port))
 
while True:
 
    # maintains a list of possible input streams
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
 
    """ There are two possible input situations. Either the
    user wants to give manual input to send to other people,
    or the server is sending a message to be printed on the
    screen. Select returns from sockets_list, the stream that
    is reader for input. So for example, if the server wants
    to send a message, then the if condition will hold true
    below.If the user wants to send a message, the else
    condition will evaluate as true"""
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
 
    for socks in read_sockets:
        if socks == server:
            message = socks.recv(2048)
            print (message)
        else:
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            server.send(message)
            sys.stdout.write("<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.flush()
server.close()
```

and then, on a Windows 10 computer, I run

```
python client.py 192.168.0.41 6677 (my server's broadcast address, read off ifconfig)
```

The client then connects successfully to the server, as can be seen on the server. But, the Windows computer does not join the chat, rather reading the error "[WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket".

I was able to get it to work on macbook to linux. Is this something to do with a Windows firewall?

Comment: On an unrelated note, the value you pass to `listen` isn't the number of active connections you can have. It's the number of connections queued waiting to be accepted. It should usually be rather low, `5` is a common value.

Comment: As for the error you get, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question ([edit] it), and also add a comment on the line in the code where you get it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the student's Windows computer, but I will later. The error has also been (with a different IP address) "connection refused". I will add the full error later when I can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sys.stdin in select.select on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499523/using-sys-stdin-in-select-select-on-windows)

Comment: Potentially. So this suggests the code itself won't work on windows, as the select.select idea won't work?

Comment: That's correct, you need to figure out some other way to poll `sys.stdin` on Windows. Preferably something that could be portable for other systems as well (so you don't have two programs depending on system) :)

Comment: Would this fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10842772/5267913, so basically just remove the `sys.stdin` at the line in client.py `sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]`