# make python raw_input() or input() not waiting

Tags: python, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [raw_input and timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout)

`raw_input()` will wait for user input.  How to make it go after waiting a few seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential option:

```
import select, sys
r, w, x = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 3)
```

This will block for ~3 seconds - any data present will be in `r` after.