# A time limit for user input python

Tags: python, input, wait

i know you can use

```
x = input("...")
```

to ask something and wait for a response. is there a function to ask something and wait for a response and move on if no response is received in a set time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python

Comment: There's also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/7038689