# How to carry on a program after certain time waited python

Tags: python, time

I have this code:

```
while True:
    i=input'enter #enter or character:'
    if not i:
        break
```

This breaks the program if they enter `enter`, but I want it to break immediately if they don't answer after 3 seconds.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3 Timed Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input) (@mediocrity : maybe you vote his answer up if you like the result, since he had to put effort in answering the question and deserves credit) shows a nice example of what you are looking for.

I copied it here for you:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

answer = None

def check():
    time.sleep(3)
    if answer != None:
        return
    print "Too Slow"

Thread(target = check).start()

answer = raw_input("Input something: ")

print(answer)

print ("done")
```

I think the minor differences of this answer and your question you can yourself.

I hope that helps

**EDIT:** I found something really cool for Linux (I do not know if it runs with Windows) here: http://www.garyrobinson.net/2009/10/non-blocking-raw_input-for-python.html

I know it is not yet what you need, but I still post it, because it might help someone else. That is what Gary Robinson wrote:

> OCTOBER 17, 2009
>   Non-Blocking Raw_input For Python
>   [Edited Aug. 30, 2010 to fix a typo in the function name and generally improve formatting]
>
> I needed a way to allow a raw_input() call to time out. In case it's useful to anyone, I wrote this solution which works under Unix-like OS's.

```
import signal

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    raise AlarmException

def nonBlockingRawInput(prompt='', timeout=20):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        text = raw_input(prompt)
        signal.alarm(0)
        return text
    except AlarmException:
        print '\nPrompt timeout. Continuing...'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    return ''

ans = None
ans = nonBlockingRawInput("Input Something: ", 3)

print ans
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's very good however i was hoping that you would be able to bypass the input if the time was up, or in other words after 3 seconds the program would go straight to saying 'too slow'. Any advice??

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: You can give it a try, but I cannot test it with Windows

Comment: Yeahh sorry it doesn't work on windows( or mine atleast)

Comment: can you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python at @Paul 's answer. He claims it works for windows, but I cannot test

Comment: also look at @mike 's answer