# How to keep a console output pinned at the last line of console?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, console-application, python-3.6

I use a for loop to to start two functions, that basically do the same thing but accept input in different ways.
Like so:

```
for funk in (f1, f2):
    worker = Thread(target=funk, args=())
    worker.start()
```

One thread watches a folder and uses newly created (parsed) paths as arguments. The other awaits user's `input('Some prompt: ')`.

Both produce the same type of log output to the console.
After the prompt, a file will potentially be created and a lot of output will be printed. This will make a blinking cursor block buried in the text and, to the unassuming user, completely irrelevant. Also what if print is started from the other `Thread` while i'm in the middle of input(haven't tried it but it seems as a potential source of trouble).

How to pin or redraw( without repeating ) at the last line of the console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but maybe you can have the function awaiting user input refresh once in a while, by putting the code provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530613/4580098) in a loop.

Comment: Yeah, but this would leave multiple printed prompts if I understand correctly?