# how to make a loop stop with keystrokes

Tags: python, loops, timer, key, generator

Hello i have a loop its basically a name generator and i want to stop it at some point.I had the idea to stop it with a key.Because i cant stop it due to its high rate of generating words i cant input stop or anything its too fas.Like if i press Enter the generator should stop but i couldnt figure out how.And i had the idea of a timer when the generator generated 1000 words it would stop.All timers stopps/timers are accepted. here is mycode `

```
import time 

 from time import sleep

 import random 
 import string

def run_bot():
    x1 = random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    x2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x3 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x4 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    x5 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
   name = str(x1 + x2 + x3 +x4 +x5)

    print(name)


while True:
    for i in range(5):
        run_bot()
```

`

Comment: _"when the generator generated 1000 words it would stop"_ So use `for i in range(1000):` and remove the `while True` loop?

Comment: Here is a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input

Comment: you also need to use some GUI lib to catch key event...GTK3, QT, SDL2, TKINTER may be a help for this

Answer (score 1):

You could use multithreading.

Have a global varaible called something like `stop`:

```
stop = False
```

And replace your `while True` with `while not stop`.

Then you can create a function that waits for the user to press enter and call it in a new thread so it does not interrupt your name generation:

```
from threading import Thread

def wait_for_stop():
    input()
    stop = True

Thread(target=wait_for_stop).start()
```

Just call those lines before entering the while loop and everything should be working fine.