# how to stop input() from main thread in python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, input

What should be written in kill_input() instead of pass to stop input() and terminate the program?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import threading, time

running = True

def kill_input():
  pass

def input_reader():
  while running:
    print(input())

t = threading.Thread(target = input_reader)
t.start()

time.sleep(2)
kill_input()
print('bye')
```

Comment: If you want an input prompt with a timeout you may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/3488231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with setting the thread to daemon.
t.daemon = True
t.start()

If there are no hanging non-daemon threads it will terminate automatically.