# How to add a time limit on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to add a time limit for user input in Python?

something like this:

```
while true:
     ans = input("please enter a text")
     timelimit = 5 seconds
     if timelimit = reach
     restart the code
```

the given code in the other solution is that if the time runs out it still asking for input and not restarting is there any way I can restart the script or loop it out after time runs out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 Timed Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard input with timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python)

Comment: i don't get the code to loop

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @roganjosh what I want to happen is that if the user don't input anything it will restart from the beginning

Comment: Yep, which is exactly what I linked to

Comment: @roganjosh

import time
from threading import Thread

answer = None

def check():
    time.sleep(2)
    if answer != None:
        return
    print( "Too Slow")
Thread(target = check).start()

answer = input("Input something: ")

this is the code but when it  times up I want to restart the timer how can I do it?