# How can I monitor client side inputs and send input requests from server every 5 seconds if no input is received?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set up tcp server and client where server monitors client input and sends a request every 3 seconds if no input is received. Then client replies with its time. This goes on in an infinite loop. Also, they both have an option to exit the infinite loop. I don't know how to add the exit functionality as send(), recv() and input() block the code execution.

I have tried using select with 3 second timeout, it didn't work. I have tried threading but it stops after first user input until the next user input. I want it to go infinitely unless user wants to exit.

Infinite loop for communication:

client side:

```
while True:
    data = ClientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print("From Server: " + str(data))
    # clear string
    data = ''
    data = 'Random Number: ' + str(random.randint(1, 101))
    current_time = datetime.now()
    required_format = (current_time.strftime("Date: %Y-%m-%d\tTime: %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
    data = data + "\t" + required_format + '\n'
    ClientSocket.send(data.encode())
    print("Sending: " + str(data))
    data = ''
```

Server Side:

```
while True:
    data = ''
    data = 'Please enter a response.'
    print("Sending: " + str(data))
    ClientSocket.send(data.encode())
    # clear string
    data = ''
    data = ClientSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print("From Client: " + str(data))
```

Select function that i tried:

```
readlist = [ClientSocket]

incoming = select.select(readlist, [], [], 3)

if incoming:
    #perform a chat function here

else:
         #use the code mentioned above for automated messages
```

This is the threading feature that I tried:
[Python 3 Timed Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input)

How can I restrict time for recv(), send() and input() while sending and receiving message request and acknowledgements?

Please let me know if you would like to see the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you

`server.py`

```
inputs = [server]
outputs = []
messages = {}


try:
    while inputs:
        readable, writable, error = select.select(inputs, outputs, [])

        for sock in readable:
            if sock is server:
                client, _ = sock.accept()
                inputs.append(client)
                messages[client] = Queue()
            else:
                data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
                if data and data != 'exit\n':
                    print(data)
                    messages[sock].put(data)
                    if sock not in outputs:
                        outputs.append(sock)
                else:
                    print('Client disconnected')
                    sock.close()
                    inputs.remove(sock)
        for sock in outputs:
            try:
                msg = messages[sock].get_nowait()
                sock.send(msg.upper().encode())
            except Empty:
                sleep(3)
                sock.send(b'No data recieved')
                outputs.remove(sock)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.close()
```

`client.py`

```
inputs = [sock, sys.stdin]

while inputs:
    readable, _, _ = select.select(inputs, [], [])

    for s in readable:
        if s is sock:
            data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
            if data:
                if data.lower() != 'exit':
                    print('{}'.format(data))
                    sys.stdout.write('You: ')
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                else:
                    exiting('Server')
            else:
                exiting('Server')
        else:
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            sock.send(msg.encode())
            sys.stdout.write('You: ')
```

Comment: @Abhishek Please consider upvoting the answer.

Comment: I am at reputatinon 13, i can only do so after i reach level 15.