# How to make a thread dependet from another in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-input

I used the following code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828224/how-can-i-stop-the-input-function-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os

answer = None

def ask():
    global start_time, answer
    start_time = time.time()
    answer = input("Enter a number:\n")
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return 0


def timing(t):
    global answer
    time_limit = t
    while True:
        time_taken = time.time() - start_time
        if answer is not None:
            print(f"You took {time_taken} seconds to enter a number.")
            time_limit += 3
            answer = None
        if time_taken > time_limit:
            print("Time's up !!! \n"
                  f"You took {time_taken} seconds.")
            os._exit(1)
        time.sleep(0.001)


t1 = Thread(target=ask)
t2 = Thread(target=timing, args=(5,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

What I'm trying to do is, if the user enters a number before 5 seconds have passed he got 3 more seconds to type another number. That repeats until the time has passed. But I don't know how to make it "recall" the function 'ask'.

I am happy for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can alter a logic a little bit:

- when you enter the function `ask()`, calculate the `final_time` (which is from now on 5 seconds in the future)
- in the thread `timing()` you only check if this `final_time` is still in future, if not you exit the script
- if user enters the number in the interval, increase this `final_time` by 3 seconds:

```py
import datetime
import os
import time
from threading import Thread


def ask():
    global final_time

    final_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)

    while True:
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        answer = input("Enter a number:\n")
        time_taken = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).seconds

        final_time += datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)

        print(f"You took {time_taken} seconds to enter a number.")
        print(
            f"You have {(final_time - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds} seconds still left."
        )


def timing():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.001)

        if final_time < datetime.datetime.now():
            print("Time's up !!!")
            os._exit(1)


t1 = Thread(target=ask)
t2 = Thread(target=timing)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Prints (for example):

```
Enter a number:
1
You took 0 seconds to enter a number.
You have 7 still left.
Enter a number:
2
You took 1 seconds to enter a number.
You have 8 still left.
Enter a number:
1
You took 3 seconds to enter a number.
You have 8 still left.
Enter a number:
1
You took 5 seconds to enter a number.
You have 6 still left.
Enter a number:
Time's up !!!
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. Do you think it could be possible to print the remaining time as a countdown? So that the user can see when his time is up?

Comment: @undefined That's more complicated - you should then use some terminal painting module such as https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html But that's other type of question.

Answer (score 1):

To make a thread dependent on another in Python, you can use the `join ()` method of the Thread class. The `join()` method blocks the calling thread until the thread whose `join()` method is called terminates. This way, you can ensure that one thread finishes before another thread starts.

For example, if you want to make the thread t2 dependent on the thread t1, you can write:

```
t1 = Thread(target=ask) t2 = Thread(target=timing, args=(5,))

t1.start() t1.join() # wait for t1 to finish t2.start()
```

This will make sure that the thread t2 only starts after the thread t1 has finished.

Here is the modified code for your program:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os

answer = None

def ask():
    global start_time, answer
    start_time = time.time()
    answer = input("Enter a number:\n")
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return 0


def timing(t):
    global answer
    time_limit = t
    while True:
        time_taken = time.time() - start_time
        if answer is not None:
            print(f"You took {time_taken} seconds to enter a number.")
            time_limit += 3
            answer = None
        if time_taken > time_limit:
            print("Time's up !!! \n"
                  f"You took {time_taken} seconds.")
            os._exit(1)
        time.sleep(0.001)


t1 = Thread(target=ask)
t2 = Thread(target=timing, args=(5,))

t1.start()
t1.join() # wait for t1 to finish
t2.start()
```