# python timer for input

Tags: python, time

I wrote a quiz program in `python`. Here is the chunk of the code

```
count = 0
while count < 100:
    answer = "something"
    while input() != answer:
        print("WRONG")
    print("CORRECT")
    count += 1
```

This program asks me 100 questions. I want the answer to be shown and go to the next program if I get stuck and cannot type in any answer for 10 seconds.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input

Comment: this question is already answered look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input) this might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-Limited Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout)