# Python telling me thread assigned outside function isn't assigned

Tags: python, multithreading, variables

I made this program to have a timed input:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def get_answer():
    answer = input ("ANSWER THE QUESTION!!!")

def runtime():
    time.sleep(1)
    timer = timer-1
    print (timer)
    if timer == 0:
        thread1.cancel()
        print ("hi")

timer = 5

# create two new threads
thread1 = Thread(target=get_answer)
thread2 = Thread(target=runtime)

# start the threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# wait for the threads to complete
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

When I run it though, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (runtime):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\user1\Desktop\import time.py", line 9, in runtime
    timer = timer-1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'timer' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this? I set the variable `timer` before the thread runs, so why isn't it assigned already?

Comment: Add *global timer* to your *runtime()* function. Also, why are you getting input in a separate thread? *timer* will **never** be zero unless you initialise it to 1 in the main program. Maybe explain what you're hoping to achieve with this code

Comment: @olvinroght I'm trying to make a timed input. Basically, it would ask for input but cancel it after 10 seconds, and the program would be able to procede without needing the user to put in input.

Comment: Do you realise that there's no [reasonable] way to kill a thread in Python. The *Thread* class certainly doesn't have a *cancel()* function.

Comment: @olvinroght Ya just figure that out when the program ran... Googlin now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-Limited Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It would have. I figured out an answer (below), but it seems some of the solutions there may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can handle input with a timer:

```
from signal import signal, alarm, SIGALRM

TIMEOUT = 5

def get_answer(timeout):
    def handler(*args):
        raise Exception('Timeout')
    signal(SIGALRM, handler)
    alarm(timeout)
    try:
        return input ("ANSWER THE QUESTION!!! ")
    except Exception:
        pass
    finally:
        alarm(0)

print(get_answer(TIMEOUT))
```

So, no threads here. If no input within TIMEOUT seconds the *get_answer()* function will return None. Otherwise it will return the user input.

**Caveat:**

Unix type systems only - i.e., this will **not** work on Windows

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Marya

Made the variable global, and put the subtracting part in a `while` loop.

```
import time
import threading as t
from threading import Thread

class StoppableThread(t.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stop_flag = t.Event()

    def run(self):
        global answer
        while not self.stop_flag.is_set():
            answer = input ("ANSWER THE QUESTION!!!\n")

            return answer


    def stop(self):
        self.stop_flag.set()


global timer
timer = 5


def runtime():
    global timer
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        timer = timer-1
        #uncomment the following line if you want it to display a countdown
        #print (timer)
        if timer == 0:
            thread1.stop()
            print ("Time is up!")
            print (f"You answered {answer}")
            break

# create two new threads
thread1 = StoppableThread()
thread2 = Thread(target=runtime)

# start the threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# wait for the threads to complete
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: The *Thread* class doesn't have a *kill()* function

Comment: Oh, I think I may have confused self.killed() as something I could use to kill a thread. Fixed the answer.

Comment: This won't really work, while loops don't work the way you think they do... What happens when the code is already in the input function call and then the flag is set?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It works fine - at the end it prints the answer (when I add in print (answer) in runtime(), and set global answer in run().