# Wait for user specific input for with a timeout in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, sleep

I want the python program to wait for user specific char input, let's say "r"/"f", and to continue according to this char.

If after n hours none of these were input, I want the program to do something else.
How can this be reached?

Comment: This contains the answer you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-Limited Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input)

Answer (score 2):

Just use this

```
from threading import Timer

timeout = 10 #here is the time in second
t = Timer(timeout, print, ['Sorry, times up'])
t.start()
prompt = "You have %d seconds to choose the correct answer...\n" % timeout
answer = input(prompt)
t.cancel()
```

Comment: When I'm doing this, script is still waiting for input even though I get "Sorry, times up" when no input was inserted. I want it to skip the waiting for input with timeout has passed.