# Python user input to wait for a few seconds if the user does not give any input nor Enter key, and then proceed further

Tags: python, input

I have the following code. I want to add if the user does not give any input nor he/she presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the code should move ahead.

```
    while True:
        user_input = input("enter here=")

        if user_input == int(user_input):
            result = 5 + user_input
            print(result)
# If the user does not give any input or presses the Enter key in 5 seconds
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: `if user_input==int(user_input)` will never be true, because `user_input` is a string and `int(user_input)` (if no exception is raised) is an int.

Comment: yes no exception is raised

Comment: If you are not on windows - https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html

Comment: I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

The part of code `if user_input==int(user_input)` is never true because input is a string by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by utilising the SIGALRM signal. Here's a pattern that you could implement:

```
from signal import signal, SIGALRM, alarm

TV = 5

class Timeout(Exception):
    ...

def get_input():
    def handler(*_):
        raise Timeout
    old_handler = signal(SIGALRM, handler)
    alarm(TV)
    try:
        return input(f'Enter something. You have {TV} seconds to respond: ')
    except Timeout:
        print('Timed out')
    finally:
        signal(SIGALRM, old_handler)

print(get_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jllobvemy's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65406321/16880681) might be what you're looking for if you're not looking to understand exactly how it works. It uses a simple, easy-to-understand module.

There are [more complicated solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/16880681) as well, but those might help you understand the complexity of setting a timeout on an input in Python. For example, using threads to count how much time has passed can be tricky and easily done wrong.

I also found another simple module named [pytimedinput](https://pypi.org/project/pytimedinput/) that could be of use in your case. I didn't test it myself, but I thought I'd put it here anyway so you can choose what suits you best. Beware though, as pytimedinput only works in a console, not in IDEs apparently.

An example for pytimedinput:

```py
from pytimedinput import timedInput

userText, timedOut = timedInput("Please, do enter something: ", resetOnInput=False)
    #resetOnInput defaults to True, which resets the timer on each keypress. This is probably not what you're looking for.


if(timedOut):
    print("Timed out when waiting for input.")
    print(f"User-input so far: '{userText}'")

else: print(f"User-input: '{userText}'")

input()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I am getting follwing error. RuntimeError: timedInput() requires an interactive shell, cannot continue. Running following code........from pytimedinput import timedInput
userText, timedOut = timedInput("Please, do enter something: ")
if(timedOut):
    print("Timed out when waiting for input.")
    print(f"User-input so far: '{userText}'")
else:
    print(f"User-input: '{userText}'")

Comment: Also, the second answer does not let me input anything

Comment: @RakeshMulik You get this error because pytimedinput apparently only works in console, not in your IDE. Also, it seems there is by default a parameter called `ResetOnInput` that is by default set to `True`. This parameter resets the timer on each input. This is probably not what you want. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, I think (feel free to correct me) that you thought you couldn't input anything with the second answer (the one using threads?). You can. the prompt is just a little unclear. Try inputting something and retry without inputting anything for ten seconds.