# Time limit for input with countdown

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, countdown

I'm pretty new to Python and I want to set an input time limit with a countdown timer which I can watch count.

I have checked other similar questions, they are mainly explaining how to set a time limit for input, but I've found nothing on making a countdown timer that can be seen ticking every second while still allowing to type something in.

I've already created a working countdown function, here's the code:

```
import time

def countdown(count):
    while count:
        timer = "00"+':{:02d}'.format(count)
        print(timer, end= "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        count -= 1
```

It counts perfectly, but the problem is that I can't quite figure out how to make this work simultaneously with the input. Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time-Limited Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input)

Comment: It doesn't work in my case or maybe i'm doing sth wrong

Answer (score 0):

If the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/time-limited-input) don't work, you can try the [pytimedinput](https://pypi.org/project/pytimedinput/) module.

**NOTE:** This will only work as on command line (will not work for ipynb).

Save your script like this (I've named it test.py):

```
from pytimedinput import timedInput
import sys 

def Input_t(timeout=4):
    userText, timedOut = timedInput("Please, do enter something:", timeout=timeout)
    if(timedOut):
        print("Timed out when waiting for input.")
        print(f"User-input so far: '{userText}'")
    else:
        print(f"User-input: '{userText}'")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        count = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        count = 2
    while count:
        Input_t()
        count -= 1
```

Then run the script `python test.py [count]` on your terminal.

and you will get an output like this:

[image]

Comment: It works but I want a countdown timer that actually displays on the screen