# Detect hanging python shell in OS X

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, terminal, stdout

I've got a program that implements a buggy library that occasionally hangs due to improperly implementing parallisation.

I don't have the time to fix the core issue, so I'm looking for a hack to figure out when the process is hanging and not doing it's job.

Are there any OS X or python specific APIs to do this? Is it possible to use another thread or even the main thread to repeatedly parse `stdout` so that when the last few lines haven't changed in a certain duration, the other thread is notified and can kill the misbehaving thread? (and then restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are looking for a monitor process. It will run a command (or set of commands) and watch their execution looking for specific things (in your case, silence on `stdout`). Referencing the 2 SO questions below (and a brief look at some docs), you can quickly build a super simple monitor.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout

```
# monitor.py
import subprocess

TIMEOUT = 10
while True:
  # start a new process to monitor
  # you could also run sys.argv[1:] for a more generic monitor
  child = subprocess.Popen(['python','other.py','arg'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  while True:
    rlist,_,_ = select([child.stdout], [], [], TIMEOUT)
    if rlist:
      child.stdout.read() # do you need to save the output?
    else:
      # timeout occurred, did the process finish?
      if child.poll() is not None:
        # child process completed (or was killed, but didn't hang), we are done
        sys.exit()
      else:
        # otherwise, kill the child and start a new one
        child.kill()
        break
```