# How do I make my code do things in the background

Tags: python, background, raw-input

While I'm waiting for an input how can I make sure my code is doing other things?
for example..

Say I want to count to 10 while I get input
That would be useless of course, but I have reasons for learning this...

```
    test = 0
    while test < 11:
       test += 1
       print test
       raw_input("taking input")
```

Obviously it's gonna stop for input each time.
How can I make it count as the user is giving input?

Comment: The key search terms would be Asynchronous and Threading.. you should find answers to the question already if you search for these terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need something that can count while the user enters input, you can use a thread:

```
from threading import Thread,Event
from time import sleep

class Counter(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        self._stop = Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self._stop.is_set():
            sleep(1)
            self.count+=1 

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()


count = Counter()

# here we create a thread that counts from 0 to infinity(ish)
count.start()

# raw_input is blocking, so this will halt the main thread until the user presses enter
raw_input("taking input")

# stop and read the counter
count.stop()
print "User took %d seconds to enter input"%count.count
```

If you want to stop the `raw_input` after `n` seconds if no input has been entered by the user, then this is slightly more complicated. The most straight forward way to do this is probably using `select` (although not if you are on a Windows machine). For examples, see:

[raw_input and timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout)

and

http://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use threads. This here is a very simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time,readline,thread,sys

def counterThread():
    t = 0
        while True:
        t += 1
        if t % 50000000 == 0:
            print "now"

thread.start_new_thread(counterThread, ())
while True:
    s = raw_input('> ')
    print s
```

In this example the program counts up and every 50000000th loop it prints now. In the meantime you can input characters, which are right after that displayed.