# Python 2.7: read from stdin without prompting

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, stdin, arduino-yun

I'm trying to make an Arduino Yun alarm system. It needs to make requests to my web server to update its stats. It also needs to monitor a button and a motion sensor. 
The Linux side is running a python script that will make web requests. I need to have the Arduino send its status to the python script. In the python script, I need to read from the Arduino side. I can do that with `print raw_input()`, but I want it to only read if there is something available, I don't want it to block if nothing is available. For example:

```
import time
while 1:
    print "test"
    time.sleep(3)
    print raw_input()
    time.sleep(3)
```

If I run it, I want it to print:

```
test

(6 seconds later)

test
```

Instead of

```
test
(Infinite wait until I type something in)
```

I've tried threads, but they're a little hard to use.

Comment: Can you use sockets? I mean, write some "mini web server" using Python. Script that open socket, and waiting for any connection.

Comment: there are many ways you could do this (sockets, telnet, files I/O, queues, ...) but I don't think raw_input() should be it

Comment: also, sys.stdin is a file object that you can read using `sys.stdin.read()`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout

Comment: http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/timeout-at-command-prompt.353297/ may point you is a profitable direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at jakekimds's comment, and I saw that I could just do:

```
while 1:
    rlist,_,_=select([sys.stdin],[],[],0)
    content=""
    while rlist:
        content+=raw_input()
        rlist,_,_=select([sys.stdin],[],[],0)
    print "blocking task - content:"+content
    time.sleep(5)
```

This will:

1. If content from stdin is available, then store it in `content`.
2. Execute a blocking task.
3. Sleep for 5 seconds.
4. Go back to step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution which waits for single line of data. Uses file-like [sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) object.

```
import sys

while True:
    print "Pre"
    sys.stdin.readline()
    print "Post"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as the script is paused as `sys.stdin.readline()` is executed.