# Time limit on input in Python

Tags: python

I've searched on the internet for a number of days even my Computer Science teacher is not sure how to do this.

I'm trying to make a game where you button for 10 seconds and then it kicks you out of input after 10 seconds. I've a number of methods but it doesn't seem to work.

```
maxtime=9.58

start_time = time.time()
z=input()
if time.time-start_time>max_time:
   distance=g.count('1')
   print("And he crosses the line with a distance of ",distance)
```

Comment: This will only work with multi-threading, with one thread monitoring the elapsed time and the other waiting for the input.

Comment: how can I do this

Comment: maybe something like this? [Python 3 Timed Input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15528939/1248974)

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html for this

Comment: I'd rather use a getch function as I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892749/6220679) or alternatively a GUI or game lib like tkinter or pygame.