# Python raw_input() only appearing after ENTER is pressed

Tags: python, raw-input

I am calling a method in python recursively where, by default, a `raw_input()` is shown. Then if I receive a message I want to have the `raw_input()` shown again - but currently this only occurs AFTER I press the `ENTER` Key.

Is there a way of forcing the `ENTER` key to be pressed by the script after receiving a message?

Note: there isn't anything wrong with my recursion as once I press ENTER the `raw_input()` is shown

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code, it will be much easier for us to understand why this is happening if we can see it.

Comment: Then why do you have `raw_input()` inside the recursive function, if you only need it once?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing. You _do_ understand that `raw_input` **always** waits for the user to press Enter, right?

Comment: `raw_input` is a function which waits for enter to be pressed

Comment: After the user receives a message, or sends a message (using raw_input) I need to call raw_input again

Comment: You mean just like a chatroom？Then you can‘t use `raw_input`, it will block, this may help you [raw-input-and-timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout)

Comment: @JoelBiffin, what is your exact input length?