# Is there a way to pause a script while waiting for user input for a certain amount of time in python?

Tags: python

Ok so I am making a script that requires me to check in every so often and if I don't, it will automatically terminate. Is there any way for the script to ask me to make an input but if I don't input within say 10 seconds then the script will terminate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input

Answer (score 0):

Could be implemented using `select` with a `timeout` parameters, see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471853/5080177

Comment: You should vote to close as a duplicate, not post a link as an answer