# waiting for user input in separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-input

I am trying to accomplish a way to spawn a thread that waits for user input; if no input is entered within 10 seconds, I want the script to kill off the spawned thread and continue processing.  I've got a way to get the input back from the thread if text is entered but I have no way to let the timeout kill off the newly spawned thread.

In the example below is the closest I have come.  I tell the newly created thread that it is a daemon and it will exit when the main script exits.  The issue that I have with this is that the thread will continue to wait until either the script exits, or the user has inputted something.

```
shared_var = ['1']
def run(ref):
    ref[0] = raw_input("enter something: ")
    print "shared var changed to '%s'" % (ref[0])

thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(shared_var,))
thread.daemon = True  
thread.start()
time.sleep(10)  # simplified timeout

#Need some way to stop thread if no input has been entered
print "shared var = " + shared_var[0]
```

I know abruptly killing a thread isn't the best way to go ([Related Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)), but I don't know how to interrupt the new thread waiting on the raw_input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use threading to get user input realtime while main still running in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768865/how-to-use-threading-to-get-user-input-realtime-while-main-still-running-in-pyth)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to time user input.  In the link that SmartElectron provided, the solution does not work since the timer is halted once the raw_input is requested.

Best solution so far is:

```
# Declare a mutable object so that it can be pass via reference
user_input = [None]

# spawn a new thread to wait for input 
def get_user_input(user_input_ref):
    user_input_ref[0] = raw_input("Give me some Information: ")

mythread = threading.Thread(target=get_user_input, args=(user_input,))
mythread.daemon = True
mythread.start()

for increment in range(1, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    if user_input[0] is not None:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case don't worry for close the thread abruptly. In link, say

It is generally a bad pattern to kill a thread abruptly, in python and in any language. Think of the following cases:

> - the thread is holding a critical resource that must be closed properly.
> - the thread has created several other threads that must be killed as well.
>
> Close database connection, files opened, etc. resources that need be
>   closed properly, in this cases close the thread properly is
>   fundamental. In this case your solution is valid.*

If this solution does not satisfy you can use [How to set time limit on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input?)