# Python FTP: "ftplib.error_temp: 421 Timeout - try typing a little faster next time" error

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have a program which interacts with a FTP server whenever the user issues a command. Here is the basic structure of my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP(host=host)
login_status = ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)

while True:
    command = input()
    if command == "abc":
        ftp.storbinary(textfile, textmessage1)
    elif command == "def":
        ftp.storbinary(textfile, textmessage2)
```

Problem is, if I wait for about 20 seconds between issuing commands (i.e if I leave the program for about 20 seconds), and tries to issue a command after the 20s gap, then this error message pops up: `ftplib.error_temp: 421 Timeout - try typing a little faster next time`

It is in my understanding that ftp servers have a time limit and will kick you after inactivity. I'm looking for a way to keep the FTP server busy and stop letting it kick my program off. Basically, any solution that prevents that error message from showing again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and if you try put a time out like this   :   ftp = FTP(host=host, timeout=100)

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar So if I put a really large number for the timeout parameter, the FTP server will have a larger timeout allowance? Also, what is the unit for the timout variable, seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: Of course not, `timeout` parameter is for local use only. If has no effect on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either:

- Login only after prompting the user.
- or keep the connection alive while prompting the user by executing some dummy commands. Typically that is done by sending `NOOP` command:

  ```
  ftp.voidcmd("NOOP")
  ```

  Though some servers ignore the `NOOP` command. Then you will have to send some commands that really do something, like `PWD`.

  With blocking `input` call, you will have to send the command on another thread, see
  [Do something while user input not received](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26307799/850848)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. One question, what does the PWD command actually do? Really, since I'm only interacting with text files in the server, any commands that doesn t affect the files is okay.

Comment: `PWD` command returns the current remote working directory. So it has no side effect on files or anything else. In ftplib, you can send it by calling `FTP.pwd` method.