# How to provide window of time for input(), let program move on if not used

Tags: python-3.x, input, time

what I have is

```
import time

r = 0
while True:
    print(r)
    r += 1
    time.sleep(3)
    number = input()
    num = int(number)
    #????????????
    if num == r:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

And what I want to do is make it so after every number printed there's a 3 second window for the user to input the value of r, and if the user does nothing then have the program move on.  How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768865/how-to-use-threading-to-get-user-input-realtime-while-main-still-running-in-pyth  might help

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working code using `signal` and `Python 3.6+` That should run under any `Unix & Unix-like` systems and will fail under `Windows`:

```
import time
import signal

def handler_exception(signum, frame):
    # Raise an exception if timeout
    raise TimeoutError

def input_with_timeout(timeout=5):
    # Set the signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler_exception)
    # Set the alarm based on timeout
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        number = input(f"You can edit your number during {timeout}s time: ")
        return int(number)
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)

r = 1
while True:
    number = input("Enter your number: ")
    num = int(number)
    try:
        num = input_with_timeout()
    # Catch the exception
    # print a message and continue the rest of the program
    except TimeoutError:
        print('\n[Timeout!]')
    if num == r:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Demo 1: Execution without timeout

```
Enter your number: 2
You can edit your number during 5s time: 1
yes
Enter your number:
```

Demo 2: Execution with timeout

```
Enter your number: 2
You can edit your number during 5s time: 
[Timeout!]
no
Enter your number:
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I forgot to mention that my code should work on `Unix & Unix-like` based OS. I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Also, under my `Ubuntu OS` and using `Python 3.6.7` i can see that: `In [5]: signal.SIGALRM
Out[5]: <Signals.SIGALRM: 14>`

Comment: Pity - nice solution anyway :) have windows running ;)

Comment: I'm getting an error that module object has no attribute SIGALRM ??

Comment: @zeurosis Are you running under Windows or Unix/Unix like operating system ?

Comment: I'm on windows     .

Comment: @zeurosis So like i said, my code example will work only in linux/unix-like systems. For windows, i have no idea.