# time out and proceed if no input() provided

Tags: python, input, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set time limit on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input)

In python 3.2, is there a way to, while waiting for a user input, count time so that after 10 seconds, the input() function is automatically skipped and script continues.

I am running the script on Windows. The objective to wait for user input (Do you want to continue y/n), in case if the user does not provide any input, the script should continue after pausing for 10 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python