# how to do things for a period of time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program in Python in which I want to request input, but only for a certain period of time. So, I would like to execute this code for 5 seconds:

```
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input()
```

What can I use to do this? I am using python 3.3.

Comment: It is little unclear, what do you mean execute it for certain period of time? Do you want to repeatedly execute the code, even after the user enters his name? or Do you want the user to enter name within 5 seconds and then disallow?

Comment: [Use select on sys.stdin with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904057/227884)

Comment: google is helpful,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input

Comment: I want to execute for a certain period of time, then move on (ie if name = None then: ____ else:_____)