# msvcrt.getch() not responding to killing its thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, msvcrt

I have a thread with msvcrt.getch()

I want to kill it.

but if i try to kill it and it's on msvcrt.getch() it will not terminate.
It will only terminate once the msvcrt.getch() line is complete.

Anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: You can use a `msvcrt.kbhit` in a loop and a flag. See [Python: Stop thread that is waiting for user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143427/python-stop-thread-that-is-waiting-for-user-input) and the answer linked in the accepted answer.