# Stopping a timer with a specific code

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Bomb timer than can be stopped at any given moment using a specific code. which is 7355608

I've tried doing this but I fail at it, also please keep in mind I'm relatively new to python.

Also, thanks in advance.

```
import time

def countdown():
    for n in range(45, 0, -1):
        print n
        time.sleep(1)
        code = int(raw_input("Enter code:"))
        if code == passcode:
            break
countdown()
passcode = 7355608
```

P.S: I know the code is really bad, because I'm new to python.

Comment: Is this for a real, actual bomb?  If so, you might want want to get a more experienced coder that can make an error-tolerant code... to avoid any accidents...  I'd say a bomb controller is probably too mission-critical for a first-time coding project.

Comment: Absolutely not. lol. I'm planning to get a Raspberry Pi to make a CS:GO airsoft prop. Thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the program what "passcode" is before the countdown() method definition, or else python doesn't know what "passcode" means. Just move the statement "passcode = 7355608" to above the method block and it should work!

Comment: It does work, but not in the way I want it too. I want it to print how many seconds left, and tell me to enter the code, without stopping the timer. This way, it stops it

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you want it to do? I assumed you were just trying to fix the exception it throws.

Comment: I think I figured out what you want. You want it to continually count down until you enter the code. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this:

```
def countdown(passcode):
    for n in range(45, 0, -1):
        print n
        time.sleep(1)
        code = int(raw_input("Enter code:"))
        if code == passcode:
            break
countdown(7355608)
```