# How do I abort reading a user's input in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, user-input

I have a thread that monitors user input which looks like this:

```
def keyboard_monitor(temp): #temp is sys.stdin
global flag_exit

while True:
    keyin = temp.readline().rstrip().lower()
    if keyin == "exit":
        flag_exit = True
        print("Stopping...")

    if flag_exit == True:
        break
```

If I type *exit* the flag is properly set and all the other threads terminate. If another one of my threads sets the flag, this thread refuses to finish because it's hanging on the user input. I have to input something to get it to finish. How do I change this code so that the program finishes when the flag is set externally?

Comment: Start having a look at the `select` module.

Comment: you could try `temp.close()`. dont know what effect that might have.

Comment: Does it need to be cross platform or Unix or Windows only?

Comment: Investigate Alex Martelli's [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2933423/298607) and use `msvcrt.kbhit()`

Comment: If you want x platform, maybe use [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell exactly what is going wrong without more of your code, but as an easy solution you could rather [exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit) which is a python built in. This should reliably terminate the application, also [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

From wim's comment:

You can use the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module to register clean up handlers

```
import atexit

def cleanup():
   pass
   # TODO cleanup

atexit.register(cleanup)
```

Comment: When giving an answer with a link, it is usually preferred to copy the critical parts of the solution directly to the answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember to do that

Comment: I have to do some house keeping (closing file handles etc.) so I can't just call exit.

Comment: Do you know about [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module?