# Is there a way to set a time limit on a line of code?

Tags: python, input

The problem that I am having is that I want to get an input from the user, however, if no input is given after a set time, then a default value is given. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate (since solutions to the input problem usually involves waiting for a character press..)

Comment: Both links provide several examples (and links to other posts) to achieve what OP is looking for.

Comment: This answer works on posix http://stackoverflow.com/a/2933402/4615680

Comment: The first linked answer is irrelevant. Alex' answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2933423/75103) is close to correct, but will eat CPU (since the sleep is in the wrong branch of the if-statement).