# Optional user input with timeout for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, input, multiprocessing

I am trying to make a code that will ask for a user input and if that input is not given in a set amount of time will assume a default value and continue through the rest of the code without requiring the user to hit enter. I am running in Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10.

I have looked through: [Keyboard input with timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python), [How to set time limit on raw_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input), [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-python-function-call), and [Python 3 Timed Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input) black boxing the answers but none of the answers are suitable as they are not usable on Windows (principally use of signal.SIGALRM which is only available on linux), or require a user to hit enter in order to exit the input.

Based upon the above answers however i have attempted to scrap together a solution using multiprocessing which (as i think it should work) creates one process to ask for the input and creates another process to terminate the first process after the timeout period.

```
import multiprocessing
from time import time,sleep

def wait(secs):
    if secs == 0:
        return
    end = time()+secs
    current = time()
    while end>current:
        current = time()
        sleep(.1)
    return

def delay_terminate_process(process,delay):
    wait(delay)
    process.terminate()
    process.join()

def ask_input(prompt,term_queue,out_queue):
    command = input(prompt)
    process = term_queue.get()
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
    out_queue.put(command)

##### this doesn't even remotly work.....
def input_with_timeout(prompt,timeout=15.0):   
    print(prompt)
    astring = 'no input'
    out_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    term_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    worker1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=ask_input,args=(prompt,term_queue,out_queue))
    worker2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=delay_terminate_process,args=(worker1,timeout))
    worker1.daemon = True
    worker2.daemon = True
    term_queue.put(worker2)
    print('Through overhead')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('I am in if statement')
        worker2.start()
        worker1.start()
        astring = out_queue.get()
    else:
        print('I have no clue what happened that would cause this to print....')
        return
    print('returning')

    return astring

please = input_with_timeout('Does this work?',timeout=10)
```

But this fails miserably and yields:

```
    Does this work?
    Through overhead
    I am in if statement
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 241, in _feed
        obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
        cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 58, in __getstate__
        context.assert_spawning(self)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 347, in assert_spawning
        ' through inheritance' % type(obj).__name__
    RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
    Does this work?
    Through overhead
    I have no clue what happened that would cause this to print....
    Does this work?Process Process-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 241, in _feed
        obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
        cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 287, in __reduce__
        'Pickling an AuthenticationString object is '
    TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\saved_programs\a_open_file4.py", line 20, in ask_input
        command = input(prompt)
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    Does this work?
    Through overhead
    I have no clue what happened that would cause this to print....
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 241, in _feed
        obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
        cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 58, in __getstate__
        context.assert_spawning(self)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 347, in assert_spawning
        ' through inheritance' % type(obj).__name__
    RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
    Process Process-2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\saved_programs\a_open_file4.py", line 16, in delay_terminate_process
        process.terminate()
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 113, in terminate
        self._popen.terminate()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'
```

I really don't understand the multiprocessing module well and although I have read the official docs am unsure why this error occurred or why it appears to have ran through the function call 3 times in the process. Any help on how to either resolve the error or achieve an optional user input in a cleaner manner will be much appreciated by a noob programmer. Thanks!