# How come these strings are not equal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I have been trying out (for my own personal use) some peoples' solutions to timed keyboard inputs and the only one that has worked was one by Alex Martelli/martineau [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-input) I used their second block of code (starting with import msvcrt) and it worked great for pretty much everything but comparisons. I replaced the return of None with an empty string if no input is entered in time and I used some test lines as shown below:

```
import msvcrt
import time 

def raw_input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout):
    print prompt,    
    finishat = time.time() + timeout
    result = []
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            result.append(msvcrt.getche())
            if result[-1] == '\r':   # or \n, whatever Win returns;-)
                return ''.join(result)
            time.sleep(0.1)          # just to yield to other processes/threads
        else:
            if time.time() > finishat:
                return ""

textVar = raw_input_with_timeout("Enter here: \n", 5)
print str(textVar)    # to make sure the string is being stored
print type(str(textVar))   # to make sure it is of type string and can be compared
print str(str(textVar) == "test")
time.sleep(10)   # so I can see the output
```

After I compile that with pyinstaller, run it, and type test into the window, I get this output:

```
Enter here:
test
test
<type 'str'>
False
```

I originally thought the comparison was returning False because the function appends characters to an array and that may have had something to do with it not doing a proper comparison with a string, but after looking further into the way Python works (namely, SilentGhost's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)), I really have no idea why the comparison will not return True. Any response is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use `print repr(textVar)` and I'm sure a difference will emerge. `print str("some string with unprintable bytes like \x00")` is functionally equivalent to `print "some string with unprintable bytes like \x00"`; neither will make that null byte visible (on most terminals or consoles). `repr()` produces a *debugging representation*, one that uses Python string literal syntax to create an ASCII-safe reproduceable value using escape sequences for anything not printable.

Comment: Isn't it redundant to convert the `input` to a `str`? `input` is always interpreted as string.

Comment: Note that `print` already calls `str` on anything you try to print, making all your `str()` calls redundant, even for the boolean and `str` type object results.

Comment: Maybe you've got some hidden white space or newlines, try stripping it off with `textVar.strip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to see why the strings are different just by printing. String values can contain bytes that are not (easily) visible on a console when printed.

Use the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to produce a *debugging-friendly representation* instead. This representation will format the string as a Python string literal, using only printable ASCII characters and escape sequences:

```
>>> foo = 'test\t\n'
>>> print foo
test

>>> foo == 'test'
False
>>> print repr(foo)
'test\t\n'
```

In your case, you are **including** the `\r` carriage return character in your return value:

```
if result[-1] == '\r':
    return ''.join(result)
```

That last `\r` is still there, so you get, at the very least, the value `'test\r'`, but `\r` won't show up when printing:

```
>>> print 'test\r'
test
>>> print repr('test\r')
'test\r'
```

You could just *exclude* that last character when joining, by slicing the string:

```
return ''.join(result[:-1])
```

or you could use `str.strip()` to remove all whitespace characters from both the start and end of the string (including that `\r` character):

```
return ''.join(result).strip()
```

Note that there is no point in using `str()` calls here. You return a `str` object, so `str(textVar)` is redundant. Moreover, `print` will call `str()` on anything not a string object yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider this fragment of code:

```
result = []
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        result.append(msvcrt.getche())
        if result[-1] == '\r':   # or \n, whatever Win returns;-)
            return ''.join(result)
```

You can see that when building the input string, the final character that the user enters must be `\r`, which is an unprintable character corresponding to the carriage return. Therefore, the returned input string looks like:

```
test\r
```

I think you need to rework to the code to discard the final unprintable character from the input.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some unseen bytes after the string. Try to `print([c for c in textVar])` and if it shows characters lie `'\r'` and `\n` try `str(textVar).strip() == "test"` or remove those chars manually.

Comment: `bytes` is an alias for `str` in Python 2.

Comment: Printing a container will show the contents converted with `repr()` function. You are creating a very verbose `repr(textVar)` here. There is *no point* in passing a string object to `str()` again; here, `textVar` is *always* a string already.