# Check for new input before shutting down

Tags: python, input, exit

I want to check if the user entered a new input, and if not, shut down the script

I've written a small script that is intended to parse certain input, based on a set of rules. I've tried exit(),quit(),and also found to use os._exit(errorcode)

/// The part above assumes the script performed successfully, and it's requesting of the user if it wants to re-run the script, with new input///

```
print("Enter a new number: ")
time.sleep(15)
s=input()
os._exit(1)
umcn()
```

The expectation is to have the script wait for user input for 15 seconds, after the print line, and end the script if no new input is given.
"umcn()" is a defined function that should execute, if there was any input

Comment: In order to impose a time limit on input, you can't use `input` (without using threads), because it blocks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set time limit on raw\_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933399/how-to-set-time-limit-on-raw-input)

Comment: You could also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528939/python-3-timed-input