# While loop for some time

Tags: python, time, python-3.x, while-loop, clock

I am programming in Python. I have such a while loop

```
b=time.clock()
while time.clock()-b<3 :
    input("input")
```

I want to end the while loop after exactly 3 seconds, even if the user has not yet entered anything ! How can I do that?

**Edit:** What would it be if I had `data=s.recv(1024)` where s is a socket, rather than `input("input")` ?

Is there a general solution to such a problem?

**Edit2:** I am using Python 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard input with timeout in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

`input` blocks on user input, so you'll have to implement some asynchronous way to trigger the timeout event (or trigger on user input)

Luckily, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python) seems to have just the thing!

**edit**: and if you're not using Python 3, you should probably be using `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: Thanks ! And what would it be if I were waiting for a message (s.recv(1024)) ? I also need a solution to this problem.

Comment: If you're waiting on a socket, then the `select` solution in the linked question is probably your best bet:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python/2904057#2904057

Answer (score 0):

You can't, using `input`.  `input` blocks waiting for the user to type something; while it's blocking, you don't have any programmatic control over what's going on.  There are ways to trigger the signal yourself (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python), as suggested elsewhere) but that's kind of convoluted.

In general, you want to be using `raw_input` in this situation, although it suffers from the same problem.  And if you're writing a serious program to interact with the user, you'll want to use a real GUI framework, which *will* allow you to do these things in a more straight-forward way.

Comment: Thanks ! As I am using Python 3, I think I have to use input. What would it be if I were waiting for a message (s.recv(1024)) ?