# How to wait for 20 secs for user to press any key?

Tags: python, python-2.5

How can I wait for user to press any key for 20 secs? I.e. I show the message and it counts 20 secs, the code continues execution either if 20 secs are passed OR if user pressed any key. How can I do it with python?

Comment: Look up non-blocking input, then implement that in a while loop that checks the current time compared to the starting time.

Comment: @Lanaru: why a while loop? Sounds like a bad case of busy-waiting. Something like `select()` with a timeout could do the same thing.

Comment: _press any key_ is not equal _input any string_

Comment: I did see a cross-platform answer using pygame.. but there has to be a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard input with timeout in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on Windows:

```
def wait_for_user(secs):
    import msvcrt
    import time
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()
            break
        if time.time() - start > secs:
            break
```

Comment: It's a little petty, but if someone hits a character during the sleep, you're waiting for no reason. Best to compare the time rather than sleep.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use `select` to check the values, but I don't like it, I feel like I'm wasting my time.
On the other hand you can use signaling on Linux systems to handle the problem. after a certain amount of time, a exception will be raised, `try` fails and code continues in `except` :

```
import signal

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    raise AlarmException

def nonBlockingRawInput(prompt='', timeout=20):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        text = raw_input(prompt)
        signal.alarm(0)
        return text
    except AlarmException:
        print '\nPrompt timeout. Continuing...'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    return ''
```

The code has been taken from [here](http://www.garyrobinson.net/2009/10/non-blocking-raw_input-for-python.html)

Comment: Also in your special case it has another pitfall which is `raw_input` waits for you to enter `\n` at end, because Python is in line buffered mode by default.

Answer (score 0):

(Warning: untested code)

Something like:

```
 import sys
 import select

 rlist, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout=20)
 if len(rlist) == 0:
     print "user didnt input anything within 20 secs"
 else:
     print "user input something within 20 secs. Now you just have to read it"
```

**edit** see: http://docs.python.org/library/select.html

Comment: I didn't know about the select module, that's good to know about. I just tested it on windows, and it didn't work. From the docs:
Note: File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying select() function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock.

Comment: @BrendenBrown: Wow, I had no idea. Thank you for the update (this furthers my confusion at Windows development ...)