# How to Read Keyboard Input One Char at a time with a timer with Python

Tags: python, linux, input

I am trying to figure out how to create a little Python script that can take the following parameters:

1. prompt - string
2. time to wait as an integer
3. number of characters before stopping

The last one is the number of characters I can enter before the program stops accepting characters and starts processing the input. I've seen some people use Python's select.select [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python), but that doesn't account for the 3rd item. I'm leaning towards curses, although I don't know if it supports a timeout which is making me think of threads. Any insights would be great! This will run on Linux with Python 2.6.

Comment: Err, `select()` can account for the 3rd item. Assuming it will return (continue loop execution) every time there's input, you can count characters and either stop or run another `select()` call.

Comment: Really? Sorry. I read the select docs, but I didn't notice that

Comment: Should I provide you with a simple example or do you want to try yourself? :)

Comment: Sure. If you could provide an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I have achieved it :D.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from select import select

def main(argv):
    timeout = 3
    prompt = '> '
    max_chars = 3

    # set raw input mode if relevant
    # it is necessary to make stdin not wait for enter
    try:
        import tty, termios

        prev_flags = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin.fileno())
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    except ImportError:
        prev_flags = None

    buf = ''
    sys.stderr.write(prompt)

    while True: # main loop
        rl, wl, xl = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
        if rl: # some input
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            # you will probably want to add some special key support
            # for example stop on enter:
            if c == '\n':
                break

            buf += c
            # auto-output is disabled as well, so you need to print it
            sys.stderr.write(c)

            # stop if N characters
            if len(buf) >= max_chars:
                break
        else:
            # timeout
            break

    # restore non-raw input
    if prev_flags is not None:
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, prev_flags)
    # and print newline
    sys.stderr.write('\n')

    # now buf contains your input
    # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

It's fairly incomplete; I just put a few values to test it. A few words of explanation:

1. You need to switch the tty to 'raw' mode — otherwise you wouldn't be able to get input without it being confirmed by enter key,
2. in raw mode the typed in characters are no longer output by default — you need to output them yourself if you want user to see what he is typing,
3. you probably want to handle special keys like enter and backspace — I've added enter handling here. Maybe you could reuse parts of `curses` for that,
4. I've assumed the timeout is '3 seconds after last key'. If you want timeout for whole process, I think the easiest way would be to get current time, increase it by timeout (i.e. get `end_time`), and then pass `end_time - current_time` in seconds as timeout to `select()`,
5. I've made unix-specific imports optional. I don't know whether it will work on Windows correctly, though.

Comment: I had actually forgotten to mention that I needed a way to hide the input from the user, but it looks like your raw mode does that for me, so this works all the way around. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. Although I'm not sure if they are not output in Windows, if that may be relevant.

Comment: It doesn't matter. This was for a purely Linux project anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. This thread is a few years idle, but I spent a good hour exploring this (and related) threads for a clean solution.  In the end, I decided to use the tool that already works well: bash's `read`.  Here is an example asking for a power level.  The first line in the `try` block addresses the question at hand (of course, this only works if you are starting your python script from a bash shell.)  Here you have 3 seconds to enter up to 3 characters.  (The rest of the `try` block converts to int and makes sure it is in an expected range.)

```
import os
try:
  pwr=os.popen('read -t 3 -n 3 -p "enter power level: " power; echo ${power:-0}').read().strip()
  print ''
  pwr=int(pwr)
  if pwr < 0 or pwr > 100: raise ValueError("valid power levels [0..100]")
  print "power=%d"%pwr
except ValueError as e:
  print "Illegal Power:", e.message
```

Comment: I've actually come here trying to find a replacement for bash's buggy read. Finally got it to return " " and "\n", but the issue that I can't seem to fix is the broken timeout. When trying to read single characters that aren't space or enter, the timeout is a MINIMUM. I.E. it always waits for the timeout to finish, even if there's a character available.