# Python3 reading input from user character by character

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a small Python program that reads the input from the user, but does not wait for the new line character.

#### working with Python 3.7

My requirements are:

- Easy to run (No need for Sudo)
- Can take every keyboard input (Including Fn or any available button)
- Can work on OSX, Windows and Linux
- Every keyboard input is received immediately

I took a look at several options, but every one of them had at least one requirement it did not fulfill:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html - Needs line ending.
- https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html - Needs Sudo.
- [How to Read Keyboard Input One Char at a time with a timer with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183472/how-to-read-keyboard-input-one-char-at-a-time-with-a-timer-with-python) - Not working, I think it is due to the Python version I'm using.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for "a small Python program" just to read one keypress, or for a library/module, or for code? The first is overkill, the second is off-topic for this site, and the third seems unlikely to be do-able in relatively few lines given all your requirements (especially working in three different operating systems). Also, do you want the kepresses in a buffer or just a note if the key is currently pressed? Do you want key releases to be noted?

Comment: @RoryDaulton - Option 3 is what I aim at.I don't mind writing a lot of code for this.

I would like to get it without a buffer, every key press.

And as a start, lets say I don't care about key releases, only key press (Which ever option that makes it easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for command line arguments maybe module argparse (e.g. you can control command line arguments for your scripts):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

and for key events maybe pynput will be useful for you (problably without sudo (except MacOS)):
https://pypi.org/project/pynput/
or use TkInter or PyGames

Comment: I need to get the input while the program is running, I don't have it as an input when starting it. How would argparse solve this?

I've looked at pynput, but due to the sudo on MacOS, it won't work for me

Comment: I think TkInter might be a good solution for me. Lets me try it later toady.
Will update later today