# Perform an action while sleeping

Tags: python, input, thread-sleep

In python, is it possible to run code or perform an action while the script is sleeping like `time.sleep()`? What I want to do is print a message and gather input from the user only until 10 seconds after the message has been printed. I initially though I could do

```
print "You have ten seconds to answer the question."
print "The question"
time.sleep(10) and input() simultaneously
print "You are out of time"
```

Is this possible? If not, is there any way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python

Answer (score 1):

While sleeping you can't do anything. Look for the alarm(2) system call on Unix/Linux to get interrupted after some time.