# I want to take input from user while a timer is running simultaneously

Tags: python

I am creating a sort of a game where the player has to guess a word within a given time limit everything is working accept i dont know how do i run a timer and take input at the same time that too in a loop.
I tried some code but it took input then ran the timer and asked input again so one happened after the other and not simultaneously
How do i fix it

Here is what i tried

```
import time
def countdown(seconds):
  while seconds > 0:
    seconds -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
seconds = 6
while seconds > 0:
    input = ("guess word : ")
    countdown(6)
```

^^ that is only a fraction of my code
Full code here - https://sourceb.in/QYk1D9O2ZT

Comment: Tip: Have the timer run on a different thread.  Have a look into the `threading` module. 1)  [Docs linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).  2) [Tutorial linked here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/).

Comment: Looks like this thread suggests how to do exactly what you want [Python multithreading interrupt input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031762/python-multithreading-interrupt-input) - not only run a timer, but actually stop the `input` function waiting for user to press enter after time has passed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " i dont know how do i run a timer and take input at the same time that too in a loop." What exactly does this mean? Is the timer supposed to make the user wait before typing again, make the user have to type within a time limit, or something else? What should happen when the timer runs out?

Comment: [Python cancel raw\_input/input via writing to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455759)