# User Input Error

Tags: python, wait, raw-input

This is another question linked off of my previous one "Python Waiting Error." You might need to see the previous one to fully understand this one. Click the link below to go to my previous question:

[Python waiting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887938/python-waiting-error)

Anyway thank you Remolten for the previous answer.

I entered your code Borrajax, and it worked. Only if I did choose an answer

```
1) blah blah
2) blah blah
3) blah blah
4) blah blah
```

It would go straight to

```
"Would you like to continue without choosing an answer?"
```

Instead of saying

```
"Your answer was incorrect."
```

And continuing on to the next question of my quiz.
How can I make it continue on to the next question WITHOUT going to the

```
other = (raw_input("Would you like to continue without choosing a answer?:"))
```

Thank you all who were patient and put up with my horribly worded question last time!

UPDATE 1: here is the whole code, Human

```
    import time
import sys, select

def timeout_input(message, timeout=8):
    print "He he! Q%s is a tricky one!" % timeout
    if message:
        sys.stdout.write(message)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    i, o, e = select.select( [sys.stdin], [], [], timeout )
    if (i):
        return sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    return ""
#This is the script for TUKT. DO NOT DELETE
score = 0
print ""
print "Welcome to the Ultimate Kirby Test."
print ""
print "Type 'yes' to begin. Type 'no' to quit. Type 'info' for how to play."
print ""
begin = (raw_input("Would you like to begin?:"))
if begin == "yes":
        print ""
        print "Alright then! Let's start, shall we?"
if begin == "no":
        quit()
if begin == "info":
        print ""
        print "Type the number of the answer that you think is correct after 'Answer='. Sometimes, ULTRA QUESTIONs will pop up. These are worth 3 points!! At the end of the test, I will show you your score. You must get over 7 right to pass. Good luck!"
#This is the first Question.
print "Q1. What color is Kirby?"
print "1) Black."
print "2) Blue."
print "3) Pink."
print "4) Technically, his color changes based on the opponent he swallows."
choice = input("Answer=")
if choice ==1:
        print ""
        print "Incorrect."
        print ""
elif choice ==2:
        print ""
        print "Incorrect."
        print ""
elif choice ==3:
        print ""
        print "Tee hee.... I fooled you!"
        print ""
elif choice ==4:
        print ""
        print "Nice job! You saw through my trick!"
        print ""
        score = score+1
elif choice > 4 or choice < 1:
        print ""
        print "That is not a valid answer."
        print ""
#This is the second Question.
print "Q2. Who turns Kirby into yarn? (Kirby's Epic Yarn)"
print "1) Elmo."
print "2) The terrible cotton wizard named the yarn lord."
print "3) A magician named Yin-Yarn."
print "4) King Dedede."
choice = input("Answer=")
if choice ==1:
        print ""
        print "Don't be silly. Elmo is copyrighted!"
        print ""
elif choice ==2:
        print ""
        print "I can't believe you fell for that!"
        print ""
elif choice ==3:
        print ""
        print "Nicely done!"
        print ""
        score = score+1
elif choice ==4:
        print ""
        print "Ha! Nice try."
        print ""
elif choice > 4 or choice < 1:
        print ""
        print "You have got to be joking."
        print ""
#This is the third Question.
print "Q3. Who is the villan in Kirby's Adventure?"
print "1) King Dedede."
print "2) The Nightmare."
print "3) Meta Knight."
print "4) All of the above."
choice = input("Answer=")
if choice ==1:
        print ""
        print "Too bad!"
        print ""
elif choice ==2:
        print ""
        print "I tricked you! Muahahaha!"
        print ""
elif choice ==3:
        print ""
        print "FALSE!!"
        print ""
elif choice ==4:
        print ""
        print "Let me think...................YES!"
        print ""
        score = score+1
elif choice > 4 or choice < 1:
        print ""
        print "You despise me."
        print ""
#This is the fourth Question.
print "Q4. In which game can Kirby combine the powers of his enemies?"
print "1) Kirby's Dream Land 2."
print "2) Kirby 64: The Crystal Shards."
print "3) Kirby and the seven stones."
print "4) Kirby Nightmare in Dreamland."
choice = input("Answer=")
if choice ==1:
        print ""
        print "Nope. Sorry!"
        print ""
elif choice ==2:
        print ""
        print "Yes! That is correct! Nicely done!"
        print ""
        score = score+1
elif choice ==3:
        print ""
        print "That isn't even a real game! (hence not capitalizing it.)"
        print ""
elif choice ==4:
        print ""
        print "No. You should be more knowledgable about Kirby games!"
        print ""
elif choice> 4 or choice < 1:
        print ""
        print "Hmph! You should actually 'try' next time!"
        print ""
#This is the fifth Question.
print "Q5. ULTRA QUESTION! There was a voting poll to see the top ten Kirby games! Which one do you think came up on top? The choices are:   Kirby 64 The Crystal Shards,  Kirby's Epic Yarn,  Kirby Super Star Ultra,  Kirby's Return to Dream Land,  Kirby and The Amazing Mirror,  Kirby Squeak Squad,  Kirby Air Ride,  Kirby's Dream Land 2, Kirby's Dream Land 3. Please type your guess in all LOWERCASE LETTERS and NO SPACES and NO PUNCTUATION! DO NOT SPELL IT WRONG. IF YOU DO, THE QUESTIONS WILL GO ON. Start!"
print ""
begin = (raw_input("What is your guess?:"))
if begin == "kirby64thecrystalshards":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbysepicyarn":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbysuperstarultra":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbysreturntodreamland":
        print ""
        print "Hurrah! You got it correct!"
        print ""
        score = score+3
if begin == "kirbyandtheamazingmirror":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbysqueaksquad":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbyairride":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbysdreamland2":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
if begin == "kirbysdreamland3":
        print ""
        print "Sorry that is incorrect."
        print ""
#This is the sixth Question.
print "Q6. Identify the picture!"
print ""
print ""
print ""      
print "   ------------------ "
print "  /                  \ "
print " |                    | "
print " |        | |         |"
print " |                    |"
print "  \                  / "
print "  /------------------\  "
print " |_______/   \________| "
print ""
print "1) A Kirby."
print "2) A walking box."
print "3) ?"
print "4) My mom."
choice = input("Answer=")
if choice ==1:
        print "FAIL!!! A Kirby has arms!"
        print ""
elif choice ==2:
        print "That is correct! It's not a Kirby because it doesn't have arms!"
        print ""
        score = score+1
elif choice ==3:
        print "No. That is incorrect. No points for you!"
        print ""
elif choice ==4:
        print "By the way, THAT IS NOT YOUR MOM!"
        print ""
elif choice> 4 or choice < 1:
        print "Wow. Really?"
        print ""
#This is the seventh Question.
print "Q7. Meta Knight really is:"
print "1) A Kirby."
print "2) A robot."
print "3) A Waddle Dee."
print "4) None of the above."
choice = input("Answer=")
if choice ==1:
        print "Nice try. YOU ARE CORRECT!"
        print ""
        score = score+1
elif choice ==2:
        print "INCORRECT! Nice try."
        print ""
elif choice ==3:
        print "HA! No way."
        print ""
elif choice ==4:
        print "Heh! It seems as if I have fooled you!"
        print ""
elif choice> 4 or choice < 1:
        print "Why don't you read the instructions next time?"
        print ""
#This is the eighth Question.
print "Q8. What is one of the main bosses in 'Super Smash Brothers Brawl' that is also a boss in 'Kirby the Amazing Mirror?'"
print "1) Krazy hand."
print "2) Mister hand."
print "3) Ganondorf."
print "4) Yoshi."
choice = timeout_input("Answer=", timeout=8)
if not(choice):
    print ""
other = (raw_input("Would you like to continue without choosing a answer?:"))
if other == "yes":
        print "Haha! Nicely done! None of those answers were correct! This was a ULTRA QUESTION in disguise!"
        print ""
        score = score+3
if other == "no":
        print "Well, we have to move on anyway. Too bad you didn't say yes......."
        print ""
elif int(choice) ==1:
        print "THAT IS INCORRECT! 'Krazy hand' is SUPPOSED to be spelled 'Crazy hand'!"
        print ""
elif int(choice) ==2:
        print "INCORRECT! 'Mister hand' is supposed to be spelled 'Master hand'!"
        print ""
elif int(choice) ==3:
        print "Ganondorf is in the LEGEND OF ZELDA!"
        print ""
elif int(choice) ==4:
        print "Yoshi isn't in Kirby!!!"
        print ""
elif int(choice)> 4 or int(choice) < 1:
        print "Go away if you want to fail."
        print ""
#This is the ninth question.
print "SOMETHING IS PUT HERE"
print ""
quit()
#DELETE THE UPPER 3 LINES OF CODE.
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have now? It seems that the `if not (choice):` should do what you want it to

Comment: That's because you didn't enter **my** code **¬_¬** Tks, tks, tks... Kiddin' **:-D** Glad to see you're doing progress!! Have fun! Btw (pretty unrelated thing, but here it goes... Did you know there's a PyGame module? ) Check it out when you have the chance: http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because that line is executed unconditionally. You need to check if the user supplied an answer to make it applicable:

```
if not choice:
    other = (raw_input("Would you like to continue without choosing a answer?:"))
```

Then that prompt will only be displayed if the user enters nothing on the prior input.