# How to prevent users from pressing key too early in a reaction time test

Tags: python, input, stdin, enter

I try to make a reaction time test in python.

The code works fine but users can press enter key too early which results in their reaction time being `0.0`.

#### Code

```
import time
import random

print('When you see GO! press enter.')
q1 = input('Type y to start:')
if q1 == 'y' or q1 == ' y' or q1 == 'Y' or q1 == ' Y':
    pass
else:
    print('---------')
    print('***END***')
    print('---------')
    quit()

print('Get Ready!')
time.sleep(random.randint(3,5))
print('---------')
print('   G0!   ')
print('---------')
a = time.perf_counter()
input()
b = time.perf_counter()

timespent =  b-a

print('Your reaction time is ', round(timespent, 3))
```

I am very new to python.
How to prevent or ignore premature key presses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue supposed

I can't figure out the issue. Seems like if enter pressed it is recorded in the STDIN buffer. When `input()` is invoked later, it will be returned there immediately - without waiting on a new key pressed. See [Python STDIN User Input Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018268/python-stdin-user-input-issue).

### Solution

But you can use any other *key input library* as explained in
[How to detect key presses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses).

#### Example with `pynput`

Install [*pynput*](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) and modify your code as shown below:

```py
import time
import random

# Use pynput to listen for key press and release events
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
    # could also react on ENTER key pressed here

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.enter:  # react on ENTER key released
        # Stop listener
        return False

# What you had so far
print('When you see GO! press enter.')
q1 = input('Type y to start:')
if q1 == 'y' or q1 == ' y' or q1 == 'Y' or q1 == ' Y':
    pass
else:
    print('---------')
    print('***END***')
    print('---------')
    quit()

print('Get Ready!')
time.sleep(random.randint(3,5))
print('---------')
print('   G0!   ')
print('---------')

a = time.perf_counter()

# instead of input() collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

b = time.perf_counter()
timespent =  b-a
print(f"start: {a}, end: {b}, duration: {timespent}")  # debug print

print('Your reaction time is ', round(timespent, 3), 'seconds')  # added unit seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the help idk much about some of the code you used but I will try to learn.