# Using keyboard input to store values of a counter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a while loop that navigates to a webpage that I manually inspect. What I need to be able to do is press the enter key and have the counter stored.
Ideally everything would work like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
import time

url = [www.example.com,www.google.com]
ff = wd.Firefox()
stored_url_number = []

i=0
while i<len(url):
    ff.get(url[i])
    time.sleep(5)
    if enterispressed:
         stored_url_number.extend(i)
    i +=1
```

Is there a simple way to create an 'enterispressed' function in python? 
 
Specifically, I want the program to run as normal to the next iteration unless enter is pressed, in which case I want it to perform the .extend(i) action and then move on.

*Many thanks*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the case "non enter pressed", somthing else pressed? Non key pressed for some time?

Comment: Non pressed key for some period of time (almost certainly will be set to the same as the sleep time on the line above)?

Comment: I added some references

Comment: ah they look really good! I'll work through them, put what I find works as an edit on your answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to get input from the user and check if it's empty:

```
while i<len(url):
    ff.get(url[i])
    time.sleep(5)
    x = input()
    if x=="":
         stored_url_number.extend(i)
    i +=1
```

You can skip the checking if you don't care what the input is:

```
while i<len(url):
    ff.get(url[i])
    time.sleep(5)
    input()
    stored_url_number.extend(i)
    i +=1
```

**Edit:**

That works for python 3.

For python 2 use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

**Edit 2:**

If you want to limit the time for the press you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Comment: I've run some test cases with this and it seems that this has a few issues. I've edited the question to reflect some of these, but the return key is not a a legitimate input for input() and giving an EOF error.

Comment: @draco_alpine I just checked it and it's works on python3 but not on python2.7 :(