# Threading Process Waits For Input

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run a background timer while running other processes. I've used thread.Thread:

```
import threading
import random
import time
import sys
def timer(limit):
    time.sleep(limit)
    sys.exit()
def code():   
    dictionary=['hello','loading','dumb']
    word=[]
    c=random.choice(dictionary)
    answer=c
    for x in c:
        word.append(x)
    y=0
    words=''
    while y!=len(c):
        x=random.choice(word)
        word.remove(x)
        words=words+x
        y+=1
    print(words)
    guess=input()
    if guess==answer:
        print('NOICE')
    else:
        print("NUB")
    permit=input('Play Again?')
t1=threading.Thread(target=timer, args=(10,))
t2=threading.Thread(target=code)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

That`s all my code. The problem is that when i run it, the timer waits for input before exiting. I want the timer to exit at ten second mark, whether or not input was entered. I thought that threading would make it so that the processes would not have to wait for each other. Help please?
Oh, and I'm only a few days into python, so please keep your explanations simple. Thanks.

Comment: You might find some useful answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python) if you're not using Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sys.exit()` in one of your threads, this does not affect the other threads. That is simply the nature of them! All threads are equal.

If you want to make a thread that will terminate when the program exits, it needs to be made into a daemon (think a slave under the master thread).

To do that:

```
slave_thread.daemon = True
```

And in your case:

```
t2.daemon = True
```

Thus, `t2` will be terminated when the main thread exits. Do not confuse this main thread with `t1`. The main thread will continue executing while there are threads running (`t1`). But as soon as `t1` exits, `t2` will be terminated, because it is a daemon.