# How can I kill raw_input function if I do not type anything after 2 seconds?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As my question Title says, I need to kill a raw_input function if line stays blank for 2 seconds. How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you might need multithreading for this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python

Comment: If you're not concerned about portability, [`signal.alarm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) is one potential choice

Comment: Anthony's solution could also work very well.  Just be aware that even if you are typing, once the timer is up it will kill the raw_input function regardless for both solutions.

Comment: If I type and it got killed after 2s can I get that input somehow?

Comment: this saves the partial input before the timeout https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336751/1248974